# org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, tibco-ems, springrunner

We have an application using Spring Boot and Tibco EMS JMS implementations. When I create the war and deploy on my local Tomcat, I can send and receive the messages with no issues. However, if I run the application from main() method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {       
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
 }
}
```

As Run as> Spring Boot App, I see this error as soon as the message is sent to be consumed.

This is where the messages is created and sent:

```
@Transactional
private void sendAndLog (Long id1, Long id2, String s, List<Mapping> mappings) {
    queue.send(new Request (
            id1,
            id2,
            s,
            mappings));
    log.info("Message sent.");
}
```

This is where its consumed - I see that error right after send() is called and never get to the receive() method:

```
Processor.java:

@Transactional
public void receive (Request mappings) {
    // Process the message
}
```

This is the Request class:

```
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id1;
    private Long id2;   
    private String s;   
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    public Request() {}
    public Request (Long id1, Long id2, String s, List<Mapping> mappings) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
        this.s = s;
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    //getter() and setter() methods.
}
```

This is the error.

What goes wrong and why I'm seeing this error "only" when run with Spring Runner and not when deployed to Tomcat?

```
2018-07-25 17:19:19.924  WARN 4796 --- [enerContainer-7] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.package.tasks.Processor.receive(com.package.dto.Request)]
Bean [com.package.tasks.Processor@475d2a6d]
; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.package.dto.Request] to [com.package.dto.Request] for org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@6d5d2920, failedMessage=org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@6d5d2920
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.package.dto.Request] to [com.package.dto.Request] for org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@6d5d2920
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:114)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    ... 10 common frames omitted

17:19:19.924 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-7] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should debug to see what's happening.
Replace parameter type for "Object", start in debug and see what kind of Object you are receiving. Try to convert the object manually in debug mode to see what's going on.

The message is confusing, look at the packaging of your app and see if you could possible have multiple dto with the same package in different jar. If you have the problem only with SpringRunner, it is possible that you have dependencies that are not present in your local Tomcat and that's why you have the error.

Also, probably not the source of the problem, but @Transactionnal on a private method is usually not working, depends on where you run the code (Eclipse run config, gradle, tomcat, etc.).  Annotation like that should go on a public method. I would have to research but my guess is that spring inject the transaction when you call a method from a component in context, when it sees the @Transactional.  Since you called the private method from another public method, Spring probably don't inject it.

Comment: As for replacing the parameter type for "Object": I changed the receive() method like: 
public void receive (Request mappings) {} to:
public void receive (Object mappings) {}

So the object I recieve, is of type: TibjmsObjectMessage, which if I call: mappings.getObject(); then it gives me an object of type: com.package.dto.Request,
which still can NOT be cast to: com.package.dto.Request class. My guess is that 
Spring Runner fails to Deserialize the TibjmsObjectMessage properly.

I changed the sendAndLog() method from private to public but it did not make a difference.

Comment: At this point, you can add a customConverter.  But I'm wondering...what do you have in the Mapping class that is referred in your Request object?

Comment: Mapping class is nothing but bunch of String and Long, it's a model for a table in DB. I know that I can add customConventer, however, its not an issue we deal in production environment when the code is deployed to Tomcat, it happens only when ran thru Spring Boot and I was wondering why.